# Run SQL scripts inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using next Dockerfile to setup postgres database engine

```
FROM postgres:9.6.5
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD xxx
ENV POSTGRES_DB postgres
ADD localDump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

i need to create ROLE **CREATE ROLE read_only;** before initializing my database and before running localDump.sql script.

So how can i run SQL scripts inside Dockerfile direct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

======================== **Correct Answer Start** ========================

According to the Postgres image documentation you can extend the original image by running a script or an SQL file.

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files and source any *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.

For your Dockerfile, you could do something like this.

```
FROM postgres:9.6.5

ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD xxx
ENV POSTGRES_DB postgres

ADD create-role.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD localDump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

You will also need the create-role.sh script to execute the plsql command

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE ROLE read_only;
EOSQL
```

Note that I'm not a SQL DBA, the plsql command is just an example.

======================== **Correct Answer End** ========================

Original answer left for posterity :

Can you use `psql` ? Something like that.

```
FROM postgres:9.6.5

ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD xxx
ENV POSTGRES_DB postgres

RUN psql -U postgres -d database_name -c "SQL_QUERY"

ADD localDump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

You should find how to run SQL Query for Postgres from bash, and then add a RUN instruction in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I had tried this command before but it didn't work, this command "RUN psql ..." gave me next error >>> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: Can you try to run this : `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`

And then check the same command from inside the container ?

Comment: how could i run "docker ..." inside Dockerfile (it's not possible) but if u asking to run it with existing postgres container not from docker file so i can said yes it's working and i had tried "psql -h localhost -U postgres -c "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx;"" and it gave me expected result

Comment: I've edited the answer to had more informations about your issue